# JFreeChart low performance for MeterPlot

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart, bufferedimage

I'm implementing a web application using spring 4.2.5 and jasperreports 6.4.3.
This app is supposed to generate a pdf file as output. There are three jrxml files:

1. firstpage.jrxml: contains logo and some titles
2. intro.jsrxml: contains some texts and a table of items overview
3. items.jrxml: contains some texts and an image to show a JFree MeterPlot output buffer image.

**The code:**

```
public void export() {    
    JasperPrint firstPagePrint = ...;    
    JasperPrint introPrint = ...;    
    List<JasperPrint> itemsPrints = new LinkedList<JapserPrint>();    
    List<Item> items = ...;    
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
       Item item = items.get(i);
       MeterPlot meterPlot = new MeterPlot(new DefaultValueDataset(item.getValue()));
       meterPlot.setRange(new Range(item.getMinValue(), item.getMaxValue()));
       meterPlot.addInterval(new MeterInterval("bad", new Range(item.getMinValue(), item.getSect1()),
                                Color.red, new BasicStroke(2f), Color.red));
       meterPlot.addInterval(new MeterInterval("weak", new Range(item.getSect1(), item.getSect2()),
                                Color.orange, new BasicStroke(2f), Color.orange));
       meterPlot.addInterval(new MeterInterval("average", new Range(item.getSect2(), item.getSect3()),
                                Color.yellow, new BasicStroke(2f), Color.yellow));
       meterPlot.addInterval(new MeterInterval("good", new Range(item.getSect3(), item.getSect4()),
                                Color.green, new BasicStroke(2f), Color.green));
       meterPlot.addInterval(new MeterInterval("excellent", new Range(item.getSect4(), item.getMaxValue()),
                                Color.black, new BasicStroke(2f), Color.BLUE));

       JFreeChart jFreeChart = new JFreeChart(item.getTitle(), meterPlot);
       BufferedImage bufferedImage = jFreeChart.createBufferedImage(555, 250);
       String tmpFile = FileService.JASPER + Util.randomNumeralString(20) + ".png";
       ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File(tmpFile));
       itemAnalysisParams.put("chartImage", tmpFile); 
       analysisPrints.add(JasperFillManager.fillReport(ITEM_ANALYSIS, itemAnalysisParams, new JREmptyDataSource()));
   }

   ...export pdf by jasper report prints 

}
```

**Notice:**

sect1, sect2, sect3 and sect4  are internal limitation for intervals.

```
sect = (maxValue - minValue) * 20 / 100
sect1 = this.minValue + sect
sect2 = this.sect1 + sect 
sect3 = this.sect2 + sect
sect4 = this.sect3 + sect
```

The problem:

The line `BufferedImage bufferedImage = jFreeChart.createBufferedImage(555, 250);` takes a long time- about 15min- to create image and it repeats for about 45 items and takes 15min*45 total time to generate report.

In advance, I appreciate any help.